# How to zoom Android TableLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, pinchzoom

I'm making a gomoku game for Android in Java.

I've created a scoreboard in the *top* of the activity and a new game `Button` in the *bottom*.

In the center, I've created 100 `ImageView`s (10 rows and 10 columns) in a `TableLayout`. It works fine in tablets, but in phones — especially in smaller phones — the `ImageView`s are **too small**, and you can't touch perfectly what you want.

I would like to implement a **zoom function**. It can be multi-touch zoom, or a `ZoomControl` `Button`, the only thing I need is to work. So I would like to zoom in and zoom out in the `TableLayout`, but the scoreboard and the new game `Button` don't do anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRowE"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twScoreboard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/result"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_span="10"
        android:gravity="center"
    />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:gravity="center"  >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView3"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView4"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView5"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView6"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView7"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView8"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView9"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewx"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView11"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView12"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView13"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView14"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView15"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView16"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView17"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView18"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView19"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView20"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView21"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView22"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView23"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView24"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView25"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView26"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView27"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView28"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView29"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView30"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView31"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView32"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView33"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView34"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView35"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView36"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView37"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView38"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView39"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView40"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView41"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView42"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView43"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView44"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView45"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView46"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView47"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView48"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView49"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView50"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView51"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView52"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView53"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView54"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView55"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView56"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView57"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView58"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView59"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView60"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView61"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView62"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView63"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView64"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView65"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView66"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView67"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView68"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView69"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView70"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView71"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView72"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView73"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView74"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView75"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView76"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView77"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView78"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView79"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView80"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView81"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView82"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView83"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView84"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView85"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView86"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView87"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView88"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView89"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView90"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView91"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView92"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView93"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView94"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView95"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView96"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView97"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView98"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView99"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView100"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>


<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRowU"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="20dip"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewNewGame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_span="10"
        android:onClick="NewGame"
        android:text="@string/newGame"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: You have given static height and width and i think this the only one screen to display in every device. So obviously you will get small images in device as per its resolution.

Comment: I created this layout for normal screen size, but I also created the other 3 layouts for the other 3 screen sizes. My problem is that if I fill a row with 10 ImageViews in a 4 col or smaller screen size phone, ImageViews will be too small to you can touch them perfectly. You have to be really skillful to touch the ImageView you want and because of this I would like to zoom in.

Comment: How about storing all the imageviews in an array. Then have some sort of scaling factor that increases when you zoom in (1.0 to 2.0 where 2.0 is twice the size) Then everytime you detect a zoom or out increase/decrease the factor and multiply the width and heights of all the ImageViews. Something like that.

Comment: On another note, have a look at the slick2d library. Using android UI components for games can sometimes be cumbersome and limiting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to change the way you're creating the grid of images altogether, by using a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) rather than a TableLayout. With a GridView, you can control how large your columns are (by calling `gridView.setColumnWidth(int)`), and also it'll really clean up your layout/make your code easier to manage in the long run. So, when your user presses your 'zoom' button, just increase the column width, have the ImageViews in each grid item `match_parent`, and Android should automatically scale the images for you. I think it will also make click events/future changes to your styling easier to handle, and make your layout xml much more manageable (fewer lines of code, more portability, fewer points of failure). For a tutorial on GridViews, just check out Google's guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

For something with more than a column/row or two of the same type of view, you really shouldn't be using TableLayout anyway.

But if, despite the above, you're *really* super attached to your TableLayout, you have a few options. The easiest probably involves putting it inside a ScrollView, and using various methods to scale the TableLayout. For instance, you could manually adjust the width and height of the TableLayout, or set a ScaleGestureDetector on it. This way, you could scale up the content, and also scroll around once it's bigger. However, I think GridView is definitely the better option, for a myriad of reasons.

Comment: I don't want to use TableLayout, I just want to solve my problem anyway. But I think GridLayout is not good for it (or I only can't use it).

Comment: For example I have a 4 cols screen and 100dp Column Width. So now I have 3 columns but if I increase Column Width for example to 150dp I have 2 columns, but Item 3, is in the 2nd row. Consequently it don't zoomed in, it only realigned the items. What I want is like digital zoom. You have a 20x20 image. If you zoom in, you can't see some of the left, right, top, down pixels, but central pixels will be bigger. Than you can move any directions to see the other pixels.